# How to use MySQL select statement to generate rows for each entry in a JSON list?

Tags: mysql, json

I have a JSON column in a MySQL table.

A column contains a list of dictionaries. I would like for each item in the list to get it's own row, with the row ID. See the example below for better understanding.

Example:

```
mysql> select id, geography from region;
+------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  id  | geography                                                                                                   |
+------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1   | [{"state": "SC", "county": "BERKELEY"}}]                                                                    |
|  2   | [{"county": "Placer", "state": "CA"}, {"county": "Sacramento", "state": "CA"}]                              |
|  3   | [{"county": "Jeff", "state": "MO"},{"county": "Charles", "state": "MO"},{"county": "Louis", "state": "MO"}] |
+------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Desired output:

```
+------|--------------|-------------+
| id   | county       |  state      |
+------|--------------|-------------|
| 1    | BERKELEY     |  SC         |
| 2    | Placer       |  CA         |
| 2    | Sacramento   |  CA         |
| 3    | Jeff         |  MO         |
| 3    | Charles      |  MO         |
| 3    | Louis        |  MO         |
+------|--------------|-------------+
```

Comment: Does the solution absolutely have to be SQL?  Could you instead use a programming language with robust support for arrays, string slicing, etc?

Comment: Yes, I need it to be in SQL. I know how to do it in Python.

Comment: Oof, that's what I figured.  Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question so that it appears like a question. I think you should brief a little bit detail as it could be easier to do with programming language rather than MySQL. You should mention why you are not using any programming language. On the other hand, you should also mention what you have tried to solve the problem. Good luck!

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: MySQL version 5.7.11, so it has JSON functionality built in.

Comment: And thanks manetsus. I was hoping it could be done in MySQL since it has JSON functionality built it, and I want to use the output for joins with other tables.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bad idea to do that, but sometimes you have to, I guess.

3 options come to mind:

1. If you're using MySQL >=5.7.8, use internal JSON-related functions
2. JSON UDF for MySQL
3. Use common_schema

Your best shot would probably be 3rd option. You should lookup common_schema.extract_json_value().